# Generating and Saving ZedGraph plots without showing on forms

Tags: c#, graph, zedgraph

Is it possible to plot data on to a ZedGraph graph and save it as a file without showing / generating a graph that is visible to the user? I'm looking to process a lot of datasets and generate a graph and saving it to a file for viewing outside of the application.

If this can't be done, would it be possible show the graph on a hidden/minimized form, save the graph, close the window, and repeat for each graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

You create and manipulate the ZedGraph control as usual, but just don't add it to the `Form.Controls` list, for example, in the `InitializeComponent()` method, comment out something that looks like the below

```
this.Controls.Add(this.zedGraphControl);
```

There are a couple of ways to save the graph

- If you want a SaveAs dialog to appear, call `SaveAs()` on the graph control.
- If you don't want the dialog, you can write out the image using `GetImage()` on the MasterPane, and then save that:

  zedGraphControl.MasterPane.GetImage().Save("test.bmp");

Comment: I have a BackgroundWorker that runs the code to generate a graph, as well as other tasks, asynchronously. I've determined that generating a ZedGraphControl on a background thread will cause the thread to not Complete (via TaskComplete event), even though the DoWork method executes. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me, I registered with

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

Comment: Sorry, I actually have an event that is fired sometime after a backgroundworker completes. The event handler generates the graph, and then kicks off that same BackgroundWorker again. The second time the BGWorker runs, it never gets to TaskComplete. I had to put the graph generation in a seperate BGWorker for some reason. It's quite strange.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code snippet to create and save the Bitmaps without any WinForms infrastructure necessary:

```
var zedGraph = new ZedGraphControl();

// configure ZedGraphControl here

using (var g = zedGraph.CreateGraphics())
{
    zedGraph.MasterPane.ReSize(g, new RectangleF(0, 0, widthPx, heightPx));
}
zedGraph.MasterPane.GetImage().Save(Path.Combine(destinationDir, "test.bmp"));
```

This should even be able to run as service without any desktop. The only downside is that you need to reference `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` to use it.

Comment: This must be an old version of *ZedGraph*. **MasterPane** is not defined here. **GraphPane** is, but it does not have the **GetImage()** method. Can you update this code, please?

Comment: This answer is from 2012. I haven't touched ZedGraph since 2013.